# Laravel add error message to validator in custom form request

Tags: php, laravel

I have a custom form request where I do some extra validation logic and I want to add an error if my logic fails but I get this error:

> Call to a member function errors() on null

Here is my custom Request:

```
if (!empty($this->get('new_password')) && !empty($this->get('current_password'))) {
    if (
        !Auth::attempt([
            'email' => $this->get('email'),
            'password' => $this->get('current_password'),
            'status' => 'pending'
        ])
    ) {
        $this->validator->errors()->add('current_password', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
    }
}

return [                    
    'first_name' => 'required|min:1|max:190',        
];
```

### EDIT complete class

```
class ProfileRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        if (!empty($this->get('new_password')) && !empty($this->get('current_password'))) {
            if (
                !Auth::attempt([
                'email' => $this->get('email'),
                'password' => $this->get('current_password'),
                'status' => 'pending'
                ])
            ) {
                $this->validator->getMessageBag()->add('current_password', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
            }
        }

        return [
            'first_name'       => 'required|min:1|max:190',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Call to a member function errors() on null

 means $this->validator is null. Please check where you have initialised $this->validator

Comment: @Sehdev it comes from the FormRequest that extens my custom form request https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests

Comment: can you pots the whole class code?

Comment: @V-K see edit for full code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to add the hook `withValidator` as laravel doc suggested.

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if ($this->somethingElseIsInvalid()) {
            $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: where do I call this withValidator() function then?

Comment: @user3652775 In the form request file.

Comment: it doesnt make sense to me I am sorry

Comment: @user3652775 Please read this doc for more understand: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: I don't see or read where I need to call this function: withValidator($validator) It just says I can make it. Okay I put it in my ProfileRequest but it's never called?

Comment: @user3652775 Given doc is for form request so obviously add this in the ProfileRequest